# How to display infomation from database on a period using symfony

Tags: php, symfony

I want to retrieve carrier information from my database to display over a 12 month period. I declared two variables $date1 and $date2 that allow to do the operations. If the $date2 == null, we must display the carriers of the last 12 months. cod_ser is the carrier field and in the period field I have inserted dates.

I tried this code but I didn't got the expected result:

```
public function getLabels($date1, $date2){
    $rawsql= "select cod_ser from public.tiers_datamart";
    $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager('dbStat')->getConnection();
    $date1 = $request->request->get("date1");
    $date2 = $request->request->get("date2");
    if($date2 == null){
        $rawsql .= "(select MONTH (period) as mois from public.tiers_datamart where period between" .$date1. "and" .$date2. ")";
    }
}
```

I expect the carrier information to be proportional to the months. Can I have some idea please ?

Comment: Either get $date1 and $date2 from the request OR pass them as parameters to your method; depending on your needs.Also you don't have to go full rawsql, you can use select MONTH in doctrine querybuilder with extensions from https://github.com/beberlei/DoctrineExtensions. You should look at both doctrine and symfony doc

Comment: You have a couple of problems, but the most dangerous is that you are highly vulnerable to [sql injection attacks](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection). The problem you are seeing is likely because you are asking for a period between `$date1` and `null`, which makes no sense; you are also missing spaces around the dates. Finally, as suggested in the the other comment you define `$date1` and `$date2` in 2 different places; just pick 1 of the methods (and hopefully not the `request` method because of my first comment).

Comment: Don't use raw SQL, use the query builder if you can, also, and I don't know if it's on purpose, but  you don't have a return statement